# Multiple font families in one sentence

Tags: html, css, font-family

In one of my divs I need to put a title with a piece of text. But the title needs to be in 3 different sizes.

Like this :

**Hello**, *my name is* ***Anonymous***

Do any of you have an idea? Because when I use different < p > classes, it starts a new paragraph.

Comment: Wrap the words in a `<span>` with a class, so you can target them with a different font.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2A6tk/

Comment: The title of the question refers to font families, the text refers to sizes, and the example has different typefaces. Whichever you want, you need some text-level markup (which should be rather obvious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span style="font-family:BLA;">Hello,</span>
<span style="font-family:BLO;">my name is</span>
<span style="font-family:BLU;">Anonymous</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *appropriate* markup. You don't find multiple paragraphs inside a single sentence, so it makes no sense to use a `<p>`. Use elements that make sense.

Look at the reason you want to change the font, and use the markup the best describes it. Are you [emphasising](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element)? [Quoting](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element)? [Defining](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-dfn-element)? Or [something else](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1)? If HTML doesn't have an element that describes your meaning, then use a [span](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (it is a semantics-free generic element).

Then apply your styles to those elements (you might want to override the default styling on the elements first).